# How to connect to MariaDB on Synology Server from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, database-connection, mariadb, synology

I want to build an application that uses a database. I have a Synology server and I want to use it as a database server. I want to build the application in .Net using Visual Studio. I have installed MariaDB and phpMyAdmin. There is already a database called 'test'. I have created a user called 'Chechy' and have set it up to be able to connect from any host. I am unable to log in to phpMyAdmin using 'Chechy', not sure if I am supposed to be able to, but I get error #1045. Logging in with 'root; works fine.

What am I supposed to enter in this screen to make it work. I have tried the server name (with and without the double backslash), and I have tried the internal ip address of the server. Needless to say, nothing has worked so far.

[image: Add connection]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Enter Synology by ssh.

- Search mysql (/usr/local/**mariadb10**/bin/**mysql**)
- Enter to mariadb with command line:

```sh
./mysql -u root -p
```

- Check user's:

```sql
SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user WHERE Host <> 'localhost';
```

- Granting User Connections From Remote Hosts:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'**192.168.1**.%' IDENTIFIED BY '**my-new-password**' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: This one worked wonders. Complementary information on grant : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB 10, port 3307:

```
localhost:3307/run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock
```

MariaDB 5, port 3306:

```
localhost:3306/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get this working. Even though this question has been viewed 7 times in 24 hours (cue sound of crickets), I will provide an answer with what I did to solve it.

I installed MariaDB on my local machine which included all the client tools and presumably drivers etc.

Then I connected with ip address as server name.

I don't know if the local install was really necessary but that's what I did and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come after:

I faced a similar problem, but was attempting to perform the connection with php, mysqli instead.

The trick was that the server name had to include the port that the database was listening to. So instead of specifying "localhost" as the server name, I had to specify "localhost:3307" instead.

More details here: [Blog Post](https://ivanchewproject.wordpress.com/2017/10/02/connecting-to-sql-database-synology-ds216j-mariadb-10/)

Answer (score -1):

For Synology ds218j and multiple wordpress site worked for me this:

```
localhost="localhost:/run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock"
```

At wp-config.php

```
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:/run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock');
```

It can be found in wp-config.php file in wordpress folder (installed by Synology OS into web/wordpress)